# Updating multiple live drupal installations from a central template

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm helping my university switch from Lenya to Drupal for their CMS. We plan on offering a drupal install to every department that wants one. The installs will all share the same codebase (the custom drupal "template" I'm developing now) but will each have their own database, allowing each site to have its own users, nodes, etc.

The problem I have is when, after making changes to the template, I'd like to update all of the installations. If the change is to core code or that of an installed module, for example, there's no problem since all installations are running off the same codebase. If, on the other hand, I need to make changes to the database, I'm screwed because there's a tonne of installed databases, and they're all different and need to be preserved. Even for simple changes like installing a new module, the module shows up fine on the list of installed modules, but I have to manually go into each installation and enable it by hand.

There must be an easier way! Is there some easy way (like a module I haven't heard about) to force drupal databases to update certain tables from a master database? I'm thinking of something similar to the "update.php" script that I could invoke en mass from drush.

Thanks for the help, all!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use drush make for that. Check out this site http://drushmake.me/ to see example of how it looks like. All you need is to install drush script to your server http://drupal.org/project/drush. And later you can build your own .make files and run it for different database.